# Matplotlib 3D plot dismiss values not in circle

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib to plot a 3D 'histogram' with a wireframe of sine and cosine values of radiants of angles. The plot forms a circle as it should:

[image]

Now I am trying to just have the circle and its hills plotted but not the values in the circle and around. 
I have tried dismissing every value that is zero with

```
hist[hist==0] = np.nan
```

but then my plot looks like this, where also some values in the circle are zero and so the wireframe plot does not 'touch the ground' anymore.

[image]

So is there a way to dismiss the values in the circle and around it but that the plot still goes all the way down to zero?

This is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

cos, sin = np.genfromtxt('out_dhdrls_test0123.csv', delimiter=' ').transpose()

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(cos, sin, bins=50, range=[[-1, 1], [-1, 1]])
hist[hist==0] = np.nan
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')

ax.plot_wireframe(xpos, ypos, hist)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to calculate the histogram in polar coordinates. This makes it easier to filter out the unwanted points according to the radius from the center.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

r = np.ones(100)*0.9
phi = np.random.rand(100)*2.*np.pi

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(r, phi, bins=25, range=[[0, 1.2], [0,2*np.pi*26./25]])
R,Phi = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])
X = R*np.cos(Phi)
Y = -R*np.sin(Phi) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X[(R < 0.75) | (R > 1)] = np.nan
ax.plot_surface(X,Y, hist.T, alpha=0.2)
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y, hist.T)
plt.show()
```

[image]